# Which Posix signals does the Dart VM listen for and use

Tags: dart, unix

The [Dart documentation notes](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.0/dart-io/ProcessSignal/watch.html) that Dart user code cannot listen to most Posix signals as they may be used by the Dart VM itself.

So which signals does the Dart VM use and for what purposes?

Answer (score 1):

To start with I found that the `QUIT` signal is used to start the Dart VMService and the Dart process will print on `stdout` the local port that it starts running the VMService and the Observatory WebUI (interface for the VMService) on, eg.

```
The Dart VM service is listening on http://127.0.0.1:35537/tlPT9YTqI-E=/
The Dart DevTools debugger and profiler is available at: http://127.0.0.1:35537/tlPT9YTqI-E=/devtools/#/?uri=ws%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A35537%2FtlPT9YTqI-E%3D%2Fws
```

And to send the `SIGQUIT` you would use the `kill` command like so:

```
kill -QUIT <process-id>
```

The code that handles that can be found in: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/bin/vmservice_io.dart#L317